# ServiceStack: Why are my calls not resolved to correct routes?

Tags: servicestack

I am using a "new" api with IReturn interface. All my calls are being resolved to /api/json/syncreply route, rather then the ones specified in the plugin registration.

If I hit the url in browser I get correct reply, so that part is working, yet if use JsonServiceClient it does not resolve the route correctly.

```
var dataService = new JsonServiceClient(baseUri);
dataService.Get(new BaseProductBenefitTypeEdit() { Code = ((BaseProductBenefitTypeInfo)obj).Code }
                             , onSuccess, onError);
```

Dtos

```
public class BaseProductBenefitTypeEdit : IReturn<BaseProductBenefitTypeEditResponse>
{
    public string Code { get; set; }
}

public class BaseProductBenefitTypeEditResponse : IHasResponseStatus
{
    public BaseProductBenefitTypeEditInfo BenefitType { get; set; }

    public List<KeyValuePair> AvailableMostCommon { get; set; }
    public List<KeyValuePair> AvailableTypes { get; set; }

    public ResponseStatus ResponseStatus { get; set; }
}
```

I have plugin

```
 public class MaintenanceModule : IPlugin
    {
        public void Register(IAppHost appHost)
        {

            //baseProductBenefitTypes
            appHost.Routes.Add<BaseProductBenefitTypeList>("/baseProductBenefitTypes", "GET");
            appHost.Routes.Add<BaseProductBenefitTypeEdit>("/baseProductBenefitTypes/{code}/editForm", "GET");
            appHost.Routes.Add<BaseProductBenefitTypeCreate>("/baseProductBenefitTypes/createForm", "GET");
            appHost.Routes.Add<BaseProductBenefitTypeSave>("/baseProductBenefitTypes/{code}", "PUT");
            appHost.Routes.Add<ChangeBaseProductBenefitTypesDisplayOrder>("/baseProductBenefitTypes/displayOrders", "POST");

            appHost.RegisterService<BaseProductBenefitTypeService>();
```

in Global.asax at the start of the application in the Application_Start i call

```
   ServiceStackInitilizer.Run();
```

which looks like this

```
 public static class ServiceStackInitilizer
    {
        public static void Run()
        {
            var type = typeof(ServiceStack.ServiceInterface.Service);
            var types = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies()
                                 .Where(x=>x.GetName().Name.StartsWith("MyApplication"))
                                 .SelectMany(a => a.GetTypes())
                                 .Where(type.IsAssignableFrom);

            var assemblies = types.GroupBy(t => t.Assembly).Select(g => g.Key).ToArray();

            new WebServiceAppHost("WebServiceAppHost", assemblies).Init();

        }
    }
```

In WebServiceAppHost Configure method i register plugins:

```
 public override void Configure(Funq.Container container)
        {


            JsConfig.IncludeNullValues = true;

            SetConfig(new EndpointHostConfig
            {
                ServiceStackHandlerFactoryPath = "api",
                DefaultContentType = ServiceStack.Common.Web.ContentType.Json,
                DefaultJsonpCacheExpiration = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0, 0),
                GlobalResponseHeaders = { { "Cache-Control", "no-cache" } },
            });

            container.Adapter = new StructureMapContainerAdapter();

            RegisterMyPlugins();
        }

private void RegisterMyPlugins()
        {
            var type = typeof(IPlugin);
            var plugins = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies()
                                 .Where(x => x.GetName().Name.StartsWith("Application"))
                                 .SelectMany(a => a.GetTypes())
                                 .Where(type.IsAssignableFrom);

            foreach (var plugin in plugins)
            {
                Plugins.Add((IPlugin)plugin.CreateInstance());
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I am using a "new" api with IReturn interface. All my calls are being
>   resolved to /api/json/syncreply route, rather then the ones specified
>   in the plugin registration.
>
> If I hit the url in browser I get correct reply, so that part is
>   working, yet if use JsonServiceClient it does not resolve the route
>   correctly.

Remember the only artifact and metadata that the service clients have access to when calling your service are the DTOs. So you need to use `[Route]` attributes in order for the clients to be able to use any custom user-defined routes.

Comment: Just before you answered I looked into the code for ServiceClientBase, and figured that it is looking for the route information in the attribute of the dto. But, do I need both parts, registration of the routes in Plugin, and annotating dto with Route attribute?

Comment: @epitka No you only need to register routes in one place - I generally prefer using `[Route]` attributes for this very reason, i.e. the Metadata becomes available on the clients.

Comment: Thank you for very fast response.